# How can I display a new "quote" everyday on my website?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, hash, hashmap

So I have a collection a quotes in a db ( MySQL ), and I want to display a new quote every day ( not every time ) I visit my site. Like quote, "a" should be displayed on November 6 and quote "b" would be displayed on November 7 and so on ...

I have 100 quotes in a table ( quotes_table ) with an integer id ( 0, 1, 2 ... 99 ).

Here's my plan :

1. I create a separate table with only 1 column and 1 row called "current_index", this will have a column called "counter", with an initial value of 0 and it increments by 1 at midnight ( i.e. new day ).
2. When the value of counter in "current_index" table becomes 100  ( 99th index is for last quote ), it is set to 0 again, so it will loop from 0 to 99.
3. For each day, I use the value of counter in "current_index" table to fetch my quotes from the "quote_db".

The problem which I see with this approach is that it is very expensive and uses valuable resources for doing shit easy work.

Can anyone suggest a better approach ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Just grab the modulus of the unixdate/day of the year (where the mod value is equal to the number of quotes in your database). Strange women lying in ponds distributing swords is no basis for a system of government

Comment: @Strawberry yes, I don't know what I was thinking.